# Use classmethod as default argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, class-method

If I do something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=MyClass.f):
         self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def f():
         print 'tump drump'
```

I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined

Obviously, I could do this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
         if a is None:
              self.a = MyClass.f
         else:
              self.a = a
```

But is there a more elegant way to use a classmethod as default argument of a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't, because the functions are created *before* the class object is. There is not class to reference here, and the use of a sentinel (like `None`) is the correct way to do this.

Note that there is no need to use an `else` suite if you assign to `a` rather than `self.a` in the `if` suite:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
         if a is None:
              a = MyClass.f
         self.a = a
```

or you could use a conditional expression:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
         self.a = MyClass.f if a is None else a
```

or even:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
         self.a = a or MyClass.f
```

if all you need to support is truthy objects (function objects always are 'true' in a boolean context, for example).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for confirming.